# why does variable 'name' doesnt need to be initialized after first use [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, html, variables, web, defined

Whenever i initialize a variable called 'name' it keeps its value through pages.

Like this:

page1.html

```
<html>
<script>
    var name = prompt("What's your name?");
    alert(name);
</script>
    <a href='page2.html'> Page2</a>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<html>
   <script>
       alert(name);
   </script>
</html>
```

So in both pages the variable name keeps the value of what it has been given in the prompt of the first page, the two pages alert the same thing, could someone explain me why this happens?

Comment: That shouldn't happen. All variables are reset when you load a new page.

Comment: Are you accessing page2.html through an iframe?

Comment: By any chance, in `page2.html`, when it alerts, does it alert but no message is shown?

Comment: Is this all your code, or just a section of it?

Comment: It can not alert the same value which initialised in page1. You may get an alert but with no text in it. If you get alert with the specified text in page2 without initialising it there, then you surely have defined it somewhere else which is used by page2.

Comment: ok i posted the full code of both pages.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Also, you generally should not have script tags defined outside the head or body tags.

Comment: im using chrome and it is just for example sorry, i know it's impossible to happen thats why im here.

Comment: @Dan, you are correct. I replicated it as well. This is very weird. Am currently researching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing isn't normal, and won't work for almost any other variable. `name` is actually a reserved variable in Javascript, which is why you're seeing interesting behavior.

All variables in Javascript are properties of the `window` object. If you create a variable called `age`, you can also access it at `window.age`. `window.name` is a special property of the current browser window that allows it to be given a name, and this value can persist between pages.

If you change the name of your variable to `age`, it will go back to working as expected -- the variable will be empty in page2.html.

[A little more about `window.name`](http://help.dottoro.com/ljqvfija.php)

Comment: Thanks! This explains everything!

Answer (score 3):

The global `name` variable is the [`window.name` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.name). It is a string that is indeed persisted across page loads in the same browsing context - if you open the second page in a new tab it should no more "work".

To avoid this, use a [safe name](http://jibbering.com/faq/names/) for your variable instead, or wrap your code in an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/592396/1048572).

Answer (score 1):

It won't keep its value through pages, and the two pages will not alert the same thing.

There must be some other code in your page that sets `name` to some value.